# Part of a cancel swipe function added to an HTML5 based eBook is breaking the text input field for a note taking input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, adobe-indesign

I'm working on developing the process for creating HTML5 based eBooks intended for both desktop and mobile use made with Adobe Indesign and exported with a plugin called In5, that allows for appending html, css, and javascript on export. The issue I've encountered is that part of the smooth swipe JS/JQuery code i found on the In5 forums breaks the text input field on desktop browsers (though for some reason not on iPad.)

```
$(function(){
  $("#container").swipe("destroy");
  var pageWidth = parseInt($(".page").width());
  var pageChangeThreshold = pageWidth*.001;
  var pageWrap = $('.pages'), startPos, vertMode = false,
  nextProp = 'left', backProp = 'right', moveProp = 'left';
  
var cancelSwipe = function(){                                       //This Function breaks the note taking for some reason, changing name does not fix. removing the function totally breaks the swiping
pageWrap.animate({left:startPos+'px'}, 'fast');
};


  $("#container").swipe({
          allowPageScroll: (vertMode ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical'), fingers:1, 
          excludedElements:$.fn.swipe.defaults.excludedElements+',.mejs-overlay-button,map,[onclick],[data-useswipe="1"],[data-tapstart="1"], .panzoom,.scroll-horiz',
        swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
            switch(phase){
                case 'start':
                    startPos = parseInt(pageWrap.css(moveProp));
                    break;
                case 'end':
                    if(distance > pageChangeThreshold){
                        switch(direction){  
                            case nextProp:
                                if(nav.current < nav.numPages) nav.next();
                                else cancelSwipe();
                                break;
                            case backProp:
                                if(nav.current > 1) nav.back();
                                else cancelSwipe();
                                break;
                        }

                    } else {
                        cancelSwipe();
                    }

                    break;

                case 'move':            
                    switch(direction){
                        case nextProp:
                            pageWrap.css(moveProp, (startPos-distance)+'px');
                            break;
                        case backProp:
                            pageWrap.css(moveProp, (startPos+distance)+'px');
                            break;
                    }

                    break;

                case 'cancel':          //These lines of code seem to break the pop-out menu on iOS, renamed from 'cancel' to 'cancelSwipe' seems to have fixed this
                    cancelSwipe();
                    break;
            }
        },
        
        threshold:4,
        maxTimeThreshold:4000
    });
})
```

The specific line in question seems to be:

```
pageWrap.animate({left:startPos+'px'}, 'fast');
```

Here is the code we created for the note taking app:

```html
    <div class="allnotes">
    <input type="text" id="textInput"><button id="add" class="addButton"></button>
        <hr>
        <div id="notes" class="notes"></div>
        <script>
            function get_notes() {
                var notes = new Array;
                var notes_str = localStorage.getItem('note');
                if (notes_str !== null) {
                    notes = JSON.parse(notes_str);
                }
                return notes;
            }
            function add() {
                var textInput = " <button id=\"goto" +$('.page').attr('data-name')+"\" class=\"gotopagebutton\">pg. "+$('.page').attr('data-name')+"</button>"+document.getElementById('textInput').value;
                var notes = get_notes();
                notes.push(textInput);
                localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(notes));
                shownotes();
                return false;
            }
            function remove() {
                var id = this.getAttribute('id');
                var notes = get_notes();
                notes.splice(id, 1);
                localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(notes));
                shownotes();
                return false;
            }
            function gotopage(destinationpageNumber) {
                var currentpagenumber = $('.page').attr('data-name');
                currentpagenumber = parseInt(currentpagenumber);
                destinationpageNumber = parseInt(destinationpageNumber.split(' ')[1]);
                var distance = destinationpageNumber - currentpagenumber;
                var offset = currentpagenumber - nav.current;
                nav.to(nav.current+distance);
                // if (distance == 0) {
                //     go(event,[{n:1,id:96334,act:'reverse'},{n:1,id:96324,act:'reverse'}]);
                // }
            }
            function shownotes() {
                var notes = get_notes();
                var html = '<ul>';
                for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
                    html += '<li>' + notes[i] + " " + '<button class=\"remove\" id=\"' + i + '\">x</button></li>';
                };
                html += '</ul>';
                document.getElementById('notes').innerHTML = html;
                var removebuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
                for (var i = 0; i < removebuttons.length; i++) {
                    removebuttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
                };
                var gotopagebuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('gotopagebutton');
                for (var i = 0; i < gotopagebuttons.length; i++) { 
                    gotopagebuttons[i].addEventListener('click', gotopage.bind(null, gotopagebuttons[i].innerHTML));
                };
                
            }
            document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
            shownotes();
        </script>
</div>
```

Could anyone help diagnose why the .animate function would break the selecting or focus of the text input field or provide another method to cancel a swipe on a touch screen device (i.e. iPad or windows tablet)?

[Heres a sample page exported showing the issue.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkjlykd5xg0z1ic/Sample%20Test.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

after the line (page: 0001.html)

```js
  shownotes();
```

add this:

```js
$("#textInput").focus();
```

that seems to fix it, you can now click in the input box, it appears something is running that prevents manual selection of it, you can see that when you try to click on it the page blinks as though some script is running to prevent it from having focus, but setting focus though jquery seams to fix the issue

I hope this helps

Comment: hmmm, while that did work on the sample file i provided it doesn't seem to work on my actual document, so there must be another interaction that is causing the issue. i'll have to keep investigating.

Comment: i think i may have found a root cause, it seems like adding an animation to the group containing the embed html notes section, or making that group a button in indesign (so that it can be shown and hidden) is causing part of the issue.

Comment: unfortunately that didnt seem to fix it. i created a html/javascript/css version completely outside of indesign and when applied the file it is still being affected by the .animate function

Comment: ok so it seems that the offending js is assets/js/in5.config.js
I notice if you put a label around the input like so:
<label>CLick here to set a new entry :
<input type="text" id="textInput" name="textInput" /> </label>
then click the label text it will aput the cursor in the input box 
I don't know how much you can change your site but I would recommend using the https://swiperjs.com/ then in the divs have the HTML that you would have had in your separate pages or embed an iframe I think that would solve a lot of your issues, I think you can still style it make it work and look the same?

Comment: that worked, why did that work? you can click the label text to focus in the input field but you still can't select the input field directly? 

as for swiperjs, thanks for the suggestion and i'll try to look into it but since i'm using indesign and in5 to generate the html i'm not sure how much i'd be able to use it if i have to manually edit the html, since this will be used to produce a multitude of ebooks on a regular basis.

Comment: yer i know it's weird, I know you say because your using indesign and in5, but it's still just a jquery plug in that you can add to the HTML and should need to alter much to achieve what you want , in the long run I think it be easier for you

Comment: I've been looking into SwiperJS as you recommended, but i'm unclear about some of the possibilities and implementation. can it be used to swipe between html pages that are saved as separate html files? all the instructions seem to imply the elements need within one primary div where the elements exist within. in addition, since i can't change the structure that is created when exporting it can i just change the css for swiper to use the classes already established in in5?

Comment: yes its a bit of a hack but if you put an iframe in thee divs that form the swiper content panels you can achieve it that way, view a working example I made here https://codepen.io/ptahume/full/RwMporQ  and the code is here https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/RwMporQ  that's basically what you want i believe, i hope this helps

Comment: so from what i've tested using iframes to house the individual html pages the swiping doesnt work, similar to the before/after images on the test page you created it seems it doesn't work when there is content other than an image or text within the div. just to make sure it was working correctly, before my iframes i added some divs with just text and confirmed those divs worked for sliding but the divs containing iframes did not. i haven't done a deep dive on the github forums but at a quick glance couldn't find a solution. any insight? and again thanks for all the feedback on this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I was away, when you say its not working, the example i posted the sliding works, I updated it to only have iframes see https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/RwMporQ you can use the arrow to slide left & right if you want to grad to slide you hae to click between the iframes as they take focus away from the slider, so could to give an example of it not working so I can better understand and help you ?